# xcode runs very slowly on Vmware

Tags: osx-yosemite, vmware

I have recently installed Yosemite on my Vmware and I have installed xcode 6 on it .But the performance of Xcode and the whole OS is bad and it's slow . 
I have 6GB of Ram and Core i3 And I have dedicated 5 GB of my Ram to Vmware but It made no difference .

What's the problem ? Is it possible to make it run nicely ?

Thanks

Comment: You could buy a Mac?

Comment: @trojanfoe . I'm trying not to . But if it's not good with that , I guess I have to

Comment: I need to know what gen is your i3 and clock speed. i3s are generally not fast enough.